# What is the difference between these if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

What is the difference between these conditional statements?

```
if ((middleOfTabIndicator < index * tabIndicatorWidth)) {
    if (index - 1 != featuredTabIndex) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

vs

```
if ((middleOfTabIndicator < index * tabIndicatorWidth) && ((index - 1) != featuredTabIndex)) {
    // Do something
}
```

All my variables are `int`. Aren't these conditions the same? When I write the first condition everything is OK but when I write the second condition the result changes. Why this happens?

Comment: “*the result changes*” - can you provide a set of input values for which this occurs?

Comment: If this is your entire code, these two blocks do exactly the same. They look different though. The cause for the difference must be outside the code you posted. Please [edit] your question and post the entire code that demonstrates the behavior you describe.

Comment: What exactly does _"the result changes"_ mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: @MTCoster Thanks. My problem solved. I was making a CustomView for my Android Application. My codes are related to each other a lot. because of that I could not add whole my code. Thank you all guys.

Comment: Please do not add `[solved]` to your title. Instead, you have the option to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer you found most useful by clicking on the green check mark under the vote counts. (It'll give you some reputation too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is common is that both IF statements from your example are unclear and would benefit of externalizing them either with a proper variable explaining their meaning or adequatly named method.

They are different constucts mostly. The first one is using nested IF statement. The second one is evaluating the nested IF statement upfront.

The first construct can cover 2 scenarios.
1)`middleOfTabIndicator < index * tabIndicatorWidth && ((index - 1) != featuredTabIndex)`
2) `when middleOfTabIndicator < index * tabIndicatorWidth && ((index - 1) == featuredTabIndex)`

While the second construct can cover oly a single scenario:

```
middleOfTabIndicator < index * tabIndicatorWidth & ((index - 1) != featuredTabIndex)
```

In a way construct number 1 is more expresive and covers more cases than construct number two. But at the same time you can epress the construct number 1 without nested IF the following way:

```
if ((middleOfTabIndicator < index * tabIndicatorWidth) && ((index - 1) != featuredTabIndex)) {
    // Do something
}
else if (middleOfTabIndicator < index * tabIndicatorWidth) && ((index - 1) == featuredTabIndex)) {
}
```

Now you have same behaviour as construct number 1 without nesting.

Answer (score 1):

In first condition you have "nested if" which means that your "outer if" is checked first then if it is true then your "inner if" (which is nested if) will be checked.
In second condition there is only one " if " but it contains two conditions and they both should be true so that if body can run.

Comment: Java uses short-circuit evaluation for the `&&` operator, so in both cases the second conditional is only evaluated if the first evaluates to `true`